# ruby executable not found on openwrt system while it is installed

Tags: ruby, openwrt

I am using `OpenWrt` system and I have installed `Ruby` using below [link](http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ipq806x/generic/packages/packages/).

I have to use `ipq806x ipks` only.

All `Ruby` packages are installed successfully but when I execute any ruby command then it throws error:

```
**/usr/bin/ruby: exec: line 5: /usr/lib/ruby/ruby2.4-bin: not found**
```

But `ruby2.4-bin` is present in the `PATH`.

Output:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ls -lrt  /usr/lib/ruby/ruby2.4-bin

-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root     4095 Feb  5 12:06 /usr/lib/ruby/ruby2.4-bin*

root@OpenWrt:~# which ruby

/usr/bin/ruby*
```

I have checked that installation is successfull.

Comment: Can you get into `irb`? Or execute `ruby -v`?

Comment: output of irb: root@OpenWrt:~# irb
/usr/bin/ruby: exec: line 5: /usr/lib/ruby/ruby2.4-bin: not found                 root@OpenWrt:~# ruby -v
/usr/bin/ruby: exec: line 5: /usr/lib/ruby/ruby2.4-bin: not found

Comment: Then you haven't setup ruby correctly. There are plenty of guides on google how setup ruby on all kinds of systems.

Comment: Setup is correct as output of which is pointing to correct location   root@OpenWrt:~# which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
All required files are available under lib:        root@OpenWrt:/usr/lib/ruby# ls
2.4          gems         ruby2.4-bin  site_ruby    vendor_ruby                          output of installed package is also showing that ruby is installed:        root@OpenWrt:~# opkg list-installed | grep -i ruby
libruby - 2.4.1-1
ruby - 2.4.1-1

Comment: share the output of uname -a

Answer (score 0):

Most probably interpreter for ruby binary is not present in the system.
check for interpreter used, like in my case it's "/lib/ld-musl-armhf.so.1"

```
root@OpenWRT:~# file /usr/bin/bc 
/usr/bin/bc: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-armhf.so.1, corrupted section header size
```

check if interpreter present in system or not

```
root@OpenWRT:~# ls /lib/ld-musl-armhf.so.1
ls: /lib/ld-musl-armhf.so.1: No such file or directory
```